# How can I open a .pdf file in the browser from a Xamarin UWP project?

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

I have a Xamarin Project where I generate a .pdf file from scratch and save it in my local storage. This works perfectly fine and can find it and open it in the disk where I saved it. However, I need to open the .pdf file immediately after creation programmatically.

I already tried different variations using Process and ProcessStartInfo but these just throw errors like "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified'" and "'System.PlatformNotSupportedException'".

This is basically the path I am trying to open using Process.

```
var p = Process.Start(@"cmd.exe", "/c start " + @"P:\\Receiving inspection\\Inspection Reports\\" + timestamp + ".pdf");
```

I also tried ProcessStartInfo using some variations but I'm getting the same errors all over and over.

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"'P:\\Receiving inspection\\Inspection Reports\\'" + timestamp + ".pdf");
p.Start();
```

Comment: How about using xamarin.essentials open browser using a `file:///`-based uri: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/open-browser?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=uwp

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your suggestion but nothing happens. I don't know if there's something wrong with the way I built the Uri or something else. This is the Uri:                                   
 Uri uri = new Uri("file:///P:/Receiving inspection/Inspection Reports/" + timestamp + ".pdf");  And the method I'm calling:              
                                                                      public async Task OpenBrowser(Uri uri)
        {
           await Browser.OpenAsync(uri, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
        }

Comment: `file:///` protocol does not work in uwp.

Comment: The better way is that use `LaunchFileAsync` method to open file with browser.

Comment: @NoelRT That is not a properly formatted file-based uri

Comment: @SushiHangover, I have tested `xamarin.essentials`, but it could not open file with `file:///` protocol in uwp platform.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I'll have to try it again later, but I totally thought we have UWP using `file://localhost/....` via LaunchUriAsync as we actually have code written and in NUnit that toggles between `file:` and `https:` based urls depending upon online/offline modes of the app. (Do you have a link that states LaunchUriAsync does not work with file-based uri? Thanks)

Comment: @SushiHangover  Please check remarks [part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync), *You cannot use this method to launch a URI in the local zone. For example, apps cannot use the file:/// protocol to access files on the local computer. Instead, you must use the Storage APIs to access files.*

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Thanks for the link, I check the code, our UWP files are via network-attached storage (intranet) based (all devices are using remote headless servers with local keyboard/mouse/monitor), and thus not local zone based, so file:// works, thanks again...

Comment: @SushiHangover  Op has saved the file in his local storage. So `file://` will not work, right?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Maybe... Normally I would say his files are local zone based, but his drive letter is `P:` in his question, **if** that is a network mapped drive, he could use the intranet-based `file://xxxx/xxx` uri and thus open it via LaunchUriAsync (using the `privateNetworkClientServer` capability via app manifest)... But I do not know what that `P:` drive really is...

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT How can I reference the namespace Windows.System to be able to use LaunchUriAsync or LaunchFileAsync. I tried looking for a reference to it or a nuget package but I can't find anything apparently. And I am getting this error message: The type of namespace name 'Launcher' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.System' whenever I try to use it

Comment: @NoelRT, `LaunchFileAsync` method invoked in uwp platform,  you need create `DependencyService` in your from client and use `[assembly: Dependency(typeof(UWPFileLauncher))]` to connect interface and implementation. And this is code [sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/App14Test).

Answer (score 1):

The better way is that use [`LaunchFileAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchfileasync) method to open file with browser. You could create `FileLauncher` [`DependencyService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to invoke uwp `LaunchFileAsync` method from xamarin share project.

**Interface**

```
public interface IFileLauncher
{
    Task<bool> LaunchFileAsync(string uri);
}
```

**Implementation**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(UWPFileLauncher))]

namespace App14.UWP
{
    public class UWPFileLauncher : IFileLauncher
    {
        public async Task<bool> LaunchFileAsync(string uri)
        {
            var file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(uri);
            bool success = false;
            if (file != null)
            {
                // Set the option to show the picker
                var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
                options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;

                // Launch the retrieved file
                 success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, options);
                if (success)
                {
                    // File launched
                }
                else
                {
                    // File launch failed
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Could not  
            }
            return success;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
  await DependencyService.Get<IFileLauncher>().LaunchFileAsync("D:\\Key.pdf");
}
```

Please note if you want to access D or C disk in uwp, you need add `broadFileSystemAccess` capability. for more please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) .

**Update**

If the UWP files are network based, not local zone based, you could use `Xamarin.Essentials` to open file with browser. And you must specify the `privateNetworkClientServer` capability in the manifest. For more please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync).