# How can I reference Windows.System namespace in a Xamarin project?

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

I am trying to open a pdf file on the browser, acrobat or any other default pdf program. For this I need to call `LaunchFileAsync()` and I need to reference Windows.System to be able to use it. However, this is not working and I can't call any reference.

I tried looking for a specific library or nuget package but I couldn't find anything. The documentation just tells me to use that namespace but it doesn't say anything about how to add the reference. I also tried using a different approach by calling `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path)` and some variations but it doesnt't work using Xamarin apparently.

This is basically what I am trying to implement but there's no namespace found event though I did try implementing it.

```
string uriToLaunch = @"file://" + @file;


var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);


var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I open a .pdf file in the browser from a Xamarin UWP project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55524430/how-can-i-open-a-pdf-file-in-the-browser-from-a-xamarin-uwp-project)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an assembly reference in the Reference menu?
In the Solution Explorer, right click your project and go to:

```
Add -> Reference -> Assemblies -> System.*
```

Also, make sure not to use platform specific libraries for a mobile project, since this will probably cause compatibility issues. `.NET Standard` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Xamarin.Essentials` as it defines the various OS dependancies for you and on UWP uses the native [Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/7c85f9cdf0562ca6ac46cf0d99aea0b6cc002b91/Xamarin.Essentials/Launcher/Launcher.uwp.cs#L17):

```
 Xamarin.Essentials.Launcher.OpenAsync
```

re: [Xamarin Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/launcher?tabs=uwp#using-launcher)

Note: Opening `file://`-based URIs is very restricted in UWP.

Comment: I tried your approach but nothing happens. The pdf is not being opened on the browser or acrobat. Am I missing something? I did try opening the file using file://. This is what I am doing:                                                                                         
string uriToLaunch = @"file://" + @"P://Receiving inspection//Inspection Reports//" + filename + ".pdf";

var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);

await Xamarin.Essentials.Launcher.OpenAsync(uri);

Comment: `...@"file://" + @"P://Receiving inspe... ` is not a valid `file://` uri

Comment: What am I supposed to use instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not targeting .NET Standard yet, make sure you do that if you want to use System libraries. There are some tutorials on this, but i highly suggest you backup your project before changing from PCL to .NET Standard

Comment: How can I make sure I am using a .NET Standard library? I can't remember what type of project did I choose when I first created my project.

Comment: For me when i navigate to my main project folder and go to options -> General the first line says "Target framework -> .NET Standard 2.0". I'm on VS Mac though, i don't know if it's the same location on windows